# Formulario condicional dependiendo de checkbox abra link jquery

Tags: jquery

no tengo codigo hecho porque no se por donde empezar y tampoco es que se mucho de jquery, lo que deseo hacer es lo siguiente; tengo un listado de nombres a los que quiero asignarles un checkbox y dependiendo de la combinacion me abra una url.

Por ejemplo

opción 1
opción 2
opción 3
opción 4

si elijo la opción 1,4 abre url A
si elijo la opción 2,3,4 abre url b

y así

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Formulario con Ajax</title>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
        <div id="formulario">
            <form method="post" id="formdata">
             
                <label for="mayor">opcion a: </label><input type="checkbox" name="opcion1" id="opcion1" required="required">
                 <label for="mayor">opcion b: </label><input type="checkbox" name="opcion2" id="opcion2" required="required">
                  <label for="mayor">opcion c: </label><input type="checkbox" name="opcion3" id="opcion3" required="required">
                <input type="button" id="botonenviar" value="Enviar">
            </form>
        </div>
       
 </body>
</html>
```

Como podría hacerle las condicionales y que me abra la url dependiendo de eso, esas son pocas opciones va a tener mas.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

*Para agregar funcionalidades al* **checkbox** *usando* **jQuery**, *puedes seguir estas indicaciones:*

La primera es agregar jQuery en la etiqueta `<head>`, este se cargará cuando la página se inicie.

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- (Se recomienda siempre usar la versión actualizada)-->
  </head>
```

Y antes de cerrar la etiqueta `</body>`, incluye el script encargado de manipular el **checkbox**.

Una vez creado el entorno, sigue las indicaciones de la documentación, lo cual te ayudará mucho en tu estudio. En el caso del **checkbox**, una de las formas de manejarlo es utilizando el método [**change**](https://api.jquery.com/change/) que retornará cualquier cambio en los checkboxes.

Esta parte del código, el `change`, detectará cualquier cambio en los campos de `check`.

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){   });
```

Dentro de la función **change**, deberás capturar todos los `checks` que se marcan o desmarcan y almacenar el resultado en una variable.

```
  var checkboxes_seleccionados = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
```

La conclusión es que cada vez que se seleccionen **checkboxes_seleccionados**, se devolverá un objeto. Puedes iterar sobre ellos si hay más de una selección utilizando un `loop`.
Ten en cuenta que al iterar sobre checkboxes_seleccionados, se devuelve el elemento y no el valor de lo que se ha seleccionado.

```
for(var i=0; i<checkboxes_seleccionados.length;i++){}
```

Es común seleccionar el elemento padre, que sería la etiqueta `label` que indica lo que se ha marcado. Sin embargo, para lograr esto, es necesario modificar el HTML de la siguiente manera:

```
<label for="mayor"> opcion a: 
     <input type="checkbox" name="opcion1" id="opcion1" required="required"> 
</label>
```

La selección del elemento padre puede realizarse tanto con JavaScript puro como directamente con jQuery.

```
$(checkboxes_seleccionados[i]).parent("label").text()
```

***código funciona**

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
  var textos = [];
  var checkboxes_seleccionados = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
 
 
  for(var i=0; i<checkboxes_seleccionados.length;i++){
     textos.push($(checkboxes_seleccionados[i]).parent("label").text());
     
    
  }
  if(textos.length === 0){
     $("#opcion").html('');

   }else{
    
    if (textos.toString().trim() .includes("opcion a:") && textos.toString().trim() .includes("opcion c:")) {
      $("#opcion").html('<a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">link a...c </a>')
      
    }else{
      $("#opcion").html('');  
     }
    
   }
     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="formulario">
            <form method="post" id="formdata">

              
             
                 <label for="mayor">opcion a: <input type="checkbox" name="opcion1" id="opcion1" required="required"></label> 
                 <label for="mayor">opcion b: <input type="checkbox" name="opcion2" id="opcion2" required="required"></label>
                  <label for="mayor">opcion c: <input type="checkbox" name="opcion3" id="opcion3" required="required"></label>
               
                
                  <input type="button" id="botonenviar" value="Enviar">  
            </form>
            <span id="opcion"></span>
        </div>
         <script src="script.js"></script>
```

**(** Cuando selecciones la opción `a` y la opción `c`, aparecerá una URL **)**

**jQuery** - Selector de elemento, [**$()**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/)
**jQuery** - Retornar o definir el contenido, [**.html()**](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

**Js** - Si una String contiene otra String, [**includes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
**Js** - Convertir un valor a una cadena, [**ToString**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/ToString)
**Js** - Si una cadena contiene otra cadena, [**trim**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar, entonces para los diferentes tipos de combinaciones creo varios  if (textos.toString().trim() .......? y si en lugar de que muestre la dirección web lo abra cuando se aplaste el botón enviar? estoy haciendo las pruebas en jsfiddle

Comment: Sí. puede crear esta lógica.